# ¿Como usar KNeighborsClassifier utilizando una matriz de distancia precalculada?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

Necesito utilizar la clase `KNeighborsClassifie` de `scikit-learn` para clasificar un conjunto de datos. En la [documentacion](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) dice que se puede usar una matriz de distancia precalculada pero lo he intentado y me da error con las dimensiones de la matriz que paso por parámetro. Después de varias pruebas logré que no saliera error. Este es mi código:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

X_train = [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
y_train = [0, 0, 1, 1]
X_test = [[1, 2], [1,3]]

# Matriz precalculada de distancias entre instancias de entrenamiento
distances_traint = pairwise_distances(X_train)
print(distances)

# Matriz precalculada de distancias entre instancias de prueba e instancias de entrenamiento
distances_test = pairwise_distances(X_test, X_train)
print(distances1)

# Crear un clasificador KNN utilizando la métrica precalculada
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, metric='precomputed')


# Entrenar el clasificador utilizando el conjunto de datos de entrenamiento y las etiquetas
knn.fit(distances_train, y_train)

# Predecir la clase para la instancia de prueba utilizando la matriz precalculada de distancias
prediction = knn.predict(distances_test)

# Imprimir la predicción
print(prediction)
```

La salida es esta:

```
[[0.         1.41421356 2.82842712 4.24264069]
 [1.41421356 0.         1.41421356 2.82842712]
 [2.82842712 1.41421356 0.         1.41421356]
 [4.24264069 2.82842712 1.41421356 0.        ]]
[[2.23606798 1.         1.         2.23606798]
 [3.16227766 2.         1.41421356 2.        ]]
[0 1]
```

Considero que la salida está correcta pero tengo mis dudas sobre la implementación que he usado ya que me pregunto por qué es necesario pasarle al método `fit` la matriz `distances_train` de distancia entre los elementos de `X_train` si realmente lo que utiliza en el método `predict` para hacer la predicción es la matriz `distances_test` de distancia entre los elementos de `X_test` y `X_train`.

Por otra parte, esto es solo un ejemplo, en la práctica yo tendría un conjunto de datos que se particionan en train y test de forma aleatoria y la matriz de distancia entre todos los elementos del conjunto de datos. Por lo tanto, tendría que buscar en mi matriz de distancia la submatriz correspondiente al conjunto de train para pasarla como parámetro al método `fit` y la submatriz correspondiente a las distancia entre test y train para pasarla como parámetro al método `predic`.

Si alguien me puede dar una opinión al respecto le estaré agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Yo también estoy aprendiendo esto, me parece que se entrena (aunque no se necesite) para ahorrar tiempo y recursos o para aumentar la eficacia del modelo.
Seguramente te ayude esta [pagina](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/sagemaker/latest/dg/k-nearest-neighbors.html)

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta. Debes participar más para obtener reputación y poder comentar. Puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [answer] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu respuesta sea marcada como aceptada.